# foreach loop only entering one record

Tags: php

If I just echo out $reasons after filling in 2 required text fields then it shows the input values for both. But if I try and insert into the database, it only inserts one record and not the second.

```
function insert_lost_reasons($link){

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_SESSION['last_id'])) {

        $message = "";
        foreach($_POST['name'] as $reasons) {
            if (empty($reasons)) {
                $message = "Please fill in all fields";
            }
        }

        if ($message) {
            echo error_message($message);

        } else {
            foreach($_POST['name'] as $reasons) {
                $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `lost_time` (`ps_id`, `reason`) SELECT ?, `lost_time_reason_id` FROM `lost_time_reasons` WHERE `lost_time_desc` = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("is", $_SESSION['last_id'], $reasons);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
                unset($_SESSION['token']);
                header("location: dash.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at your code. Think what it does. Where is the `exit()`. When does it get called.

Comment: Are you claiming that the `INSERT...SELECT...` query works? I dont think it should as you are attempting to use a parameter `?` for a column name and **thats not legal syntax**.

Comment: Like @RiggsFolly pointed out, you cannot use a parameter for a column name. Why don't you display errors. check your log file

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, again, the syntax is correct and the query works as I want it to. Rishi's answer is correct.

Comment: @Jonathan Please add the error reporting code I suggested in comment, **just to humor me**. If that actually works we all need to know about it as its is a major change in the way the `MYSQLI_` extension and MYSQL itself works

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the person who helped me with this explained it like this:  When we use a SELECT in an INSERT we must include all the values the INSERT is expecting. It is not necessary for all of them to come from the target table - for the rest you can fill in constant values or parameters. In the above we are binding two parameters. The first is the session ID that is going to go into the SELECT and form part of the data being sent to the INSERT. The second is the search description that is going to be used

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should write your foreach like this

```
else {
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $reasons) {
        $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `lost_time` (`ps_id`, `reason`) SELECT ?, `lost_time_reason_id` FROM `lost_time_reasons` WHERE `lost_time_desc` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("is", $_SESSION['last_id'], $reasons);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    header("location: dash.php");
    exit();
}
```

You are redirecting in first iteration.

Comment: You missed the SQL Syntax Error i.e. `SELECT ?, lost_time_reason_id FROM` You cannot use a parameter for a column name

Comment: The SELECT ? is correct. Rishi's answer is spot on. I needed to move by header call outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: @Jonathan Please add the error reporting code I suggested in comment, **just to humor me**. If that actually works we all need to know about it as its is a major change in the way the `MYSQLI_` extension and MYSQL itself works

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it does work. I am generating text inputs via PHP. If a user types 3, then 3 text inputs are generated. They then type into each text field and via ajax/jquery, a search is done in the database. The records display in an <li> When they click on one of those items, the text then goes into the text field but binds the id to the value, not the text value. The SELECT ? as you can see, is getting the value of the session variable as per the bind_param

Comment: as @Jonathan surely said its working I kept query as it is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you close session and exit on first foreach loop. Wait all loops and then jump with `headeer`function.

```
header("location: dash.php");
exit();
```

Do this instead:

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $reasons) {
    //Edit this for your usage
    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `lost_time` (`ps_id`, `reason`) SELECT ?, `lost_time_reason_id` FROM `lost_time_reasons` WHERE `lost_time_desc` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $_SESSION['last_id'], $reasons);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
unset($_SESSION['token']);
header("location: dash.php");
exit();
```

Comment: You missed the SQL Syntax Error i.e. `SELECT ?, lost_time_reason_id FROM` You cannot use a parameter for a column name

Comment: You are right but I don't know about is query as it is very strange. I've just point out that `close` and `header` part should be done outside `foreach` loop.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, there is nothing wrong with the SELECT ?. The header call needed to move outside of the foreach loop.